# How to run pytest.main("-v test_script2.py") when test_script2.py needs some command line arguments in order for the test functions to run?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, pytest

I have two scripts. One script parses all the arguments and decides the control flow of the script. Another script has all the test functions defined and I wanted to use pytest module to invoke the 'test_script2.py' and run all the tests. But there are some arguments that I need to pass down to test_script2.py before the test cases run.

One way I could think of was to write to a file and have test_script2.py read all the arguments from that file when it first runs. Please let me know if you have any other ideas. Your help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can create a `conftest.py` file and add options to `pytest` using `pytest_addoption` hook:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        '--arg1',
        dest="arg1",
        help="first argument")
```

Now `py.test` understands this option, so if you execute:

```
py.test --arg1 hey
```

then tests in the same directory and below can access the option like this:

```
def test_foo(request):
    arg1 = request.config.getoption('arg1')
    assert arg1 == "hey"
```